# How to restrict CPT post's fronted view only for specific user roles?

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, front-end, capabilities, user-access

I have a CPT named 'book' and I would like to restrict front-end view of this book, like specific role users can only **view** this book contents from front-end, by default anyone can see CPT posts from frontend, I have tried with **capabilities** and  **map_meta_cap** but not getting expected result.

### CPT code:

```
$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'description' => 'test book',
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => array('book', 'books'),
    'capabilities' => array(
       'edit_post' => 'edit_book',
       'edit_posts' => 'edit_books',
       'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_books',
       'publish_posts' => 'publish_books',
       'read_post' => 'read_book',
       'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_books',
       'delete_post' => 'delete_book'
    )
);
register_post_type( 'book', $args );
```

### Function:

```
      // "lite_user" is a custom user role to manage book
    $roles = array( get_role('lite_user') );
    foreach($roles as $role) {
      if($role) {
        $role->add_cap('read');
        $role->add_cap('edit_book');
        $role->add_cap('read_book');
        $role->add_cap('delete_book');
        $role->add_cap('edit_books');
        $role->add_cap('edit_others_books');
        $role->add_cap('publish_books');
        $role->add_cap('read_private_books');
      }
    }
```

by this code, any public can view/access these books from frontend but, I want to restrict this, **lite_user** role users can only able to view/access books from front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `the_content` to make sure only people with the right cap can see it:

```
function filter_the_content( $content ) {

   // Check post type is book
   // and that the current user is not lite user
   if (get_post_type() == 'book' 
        && ! current_user_can( 'read_book' ) ) { 

        // return a message in place of the content
        return 'Why do you want to see this book? You can\'t read!';
    }

    // otherwise, show content
    return $content;

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content' );
```

**However!**

This will only work for lite user, meaning that any other user (including admins) won't be able to see it from the front end.

You will have to add the `read_book` capability to other roles.

Hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Pedro, it is working well, now I can restrict public view(guest), Actually I was looking for restriction through `add_cap` itself like as backend, Buth this also brilliant solution :)

Comment: Just thought of this: nother option is hooking into `template_redirect`to do the check and redirecting to a 404 Page.